# Meaning of ST_INO (os.stat() output) in Windows OS

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Can anyone tell me what the meaning of the value for `st_ino` is when running `os.stat()` **on Windows** (Python 3.5.3)?

In earlier Python releases, this contained dummy values, but this has recently changed and I couldn't find how it is calculated/generated. I suspect that it differs based on the file system (NTFS, FAT, ...)

**Example**

```
import os
stat = os.stat(r'C:\temp\dummy.pdf')
for attr in dir(stat):
    if attr.startswith('st_'):
        print('{}: {}'.format(attr, 
                              stat.__getattribute__(attr)))
```

**Result**

```
st_atime: 1495113452.7421005
st_atime_ns: 1495113452742100400
st_ctime: 1495113452.7421005
st_ctime_ns: 1495113452742100400
st_dev: 2387022088
st_file_attributes: 33
st_gid: 0
st_ino: 10414574138828642
st_mode: 33060
st_mtime: 1494487966.9528062
st_mtime_ns: 1494487966952806300
st_nlink: 1
st_size: 34538
st_uid: 0
```

**Background**

I used the `shutil.copyfile()` function an ran into an `SameFileError`. After looking through the code (and despite what it says in the comments of `shutil.py`) the `shutil._samefile()` function does *not* compare pathnames in Windows. Instead, it uses `os.path.samefile()` which compares the `st_ino` and `st_dev` values.

Both source and target file resided on the same device (volume), which would explain why the value for `st_dev` was the identical. But I'm still puzzled as to why `st_ino` had the same value for both files.

*Remark: both files were on a Sharepoint volume mounted using webDAV, so their `st_ino` value may have been `0` (dummy), which would explain why they were equal. I'm still curious though ;-)*

**Update**

As I suspected, the value for `st_ino` returned for the files residing on the Sharepoint volume (WebDAV), was `0`, as was the value for `st_dev`. This is the reason for (incorrect) `SameFileError`. Example output:

```
\\sharepoint@SSL\AUT.pdf os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0, st_dev=0, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=4717, st_atime=1495031011, st_mtime=1495031011, st_ctime=1495031570)
\\sharepoint@SSL\ING.pdf os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0, st_dev=0, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=4722, st_atime=1495031203, st_mtime=1495031203, st_ctime=1495031733)
\\sharepoint@SSL\WAG.pdf os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0, st_dev=0, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=4710, st_atime=1495031511, st_mtime=1495031511, st_ctime=1495031912)
```

Comment: According to the Python docs, [`ST_INO`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stat.html#stat.ST_INO) represents the `inode number`. According to Microsofts' docs on [`stat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx): "The`inode`, and therefore `st_ino`, has no meaning in the FAT, HPFS, or NTFS file systems."

Comment: Thank you @JimFasarakisHilliard. I'd be happy to accept it if you'd care to post it as an answer.

Comment: It comes from the 64-bit {`nFileIndexHigh`, `nFileIndexLow`} of [`BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788), which comes from the 64-bit `IndexNumber` in [`FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540318). In [\[MS-FSCC\] section 2.4.20](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232072.aspx) it states that "[f]or file systems which do not support a file reference number, this field MUST be set to 0, and MUST be ignored".

Comment: Thus we have a particularly bad bug in Python whenever we're not ignoring a zero value in `st_ino` on Windows.