# Error during "Save and Checkpoint" when running jupyter notebook in Google DFS folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have long been using `Jupyter Notebook` inside my Google Drive and it worked perfectly. Recently I was forced to switch to the newer version `Drive File Stream`. I made my folder `Available offline`, which should mean that I saved the folder in my local storage space. When I start a `Jupyter Notebook`, it runs fine, but trying to `Save and Checkpoint` gives me an error `Checkpoint failed`. Seems like it saves the file properly somehow but returned an error.

I started the jupyter notebook by running `Jupyter Notebook` in `Anaconda Prompt`. The following error is obtained when I try to `Save and Checkpoint`. Seems like it's complaining that the saved files are the same - `shutil.SameFileError` which is really weird, as I definitely changed the notebook by having an additional `Save Attempt x` to help me tell if it saved. I also tried to delete the corresponding check point in the folder `.ipynb_checkpoints` and do `Save and Checkpoint`, but I still get the same error...

I submitted an issue ticket to Jupyter Notebook [github page](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3615), and it seems like several other people also experience the same problem, but there has been no help received.

Below is the log that I have:

`[I 10:49:44.573 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Writing_MVUE_2d.ipynb
[E 10:49:44.690 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
        result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1015, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 237, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 285, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\handlers.py", line 278, in post
        checkpoint = yield gen.maybe_future(cm.create_checkpoint(path))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 468, in create_checkpoint
        return self.checkpoints.create_checkpoint(self, path)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filecheckpoints.py", line 56, in create_checkpoint
        self._copy(src_path, dest_path)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\fileio.py", line 241, in _copy
        copy2_safe(src, dest, log=self.log)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\fileio.py", line 51, in copy2_safe
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 98, in copyfile
        raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))
    shutil.SameFileError: 'G:\\My Drive\\Research\\Camera_Project\\Writing_MVUE_2d.ipynb' and 'G:\\My Drive\\Research\\Camera_Project\\.ipynb_checkpoints\\Writing_MVUE_2d-checkpoint.ipynb' are the same file
[E 10:49:44.698 NotebookApp] {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8891=\"2|1:0|10:1525749572|23:username-localhost-8891|44:ZGE5NjFkMTgwOTI3NDFjMWJhMzY1NDIwNjhlODk5ODA=|52cc6ad64c261ccd78d2f66a0c14a95edc8468e7e4ac9c27770ce2bbebd8cd55\"; _xsrf=2|f34c78bf|7c7913196386a495e7fb6a7c3c7bbf7e|1525206477; username-localhost-8890=\"2|1:0|10:1525723124|23:username-localhost-8890|44:MGFhNmE2ZjMxZmFmNDU0M2IyMTgzNWE2NDdmMmRhMDc=|73c556d569c5f55b60a18dd36f06850f90c89c2dc329e11a4041a6c5ede7cb38\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1526327000|23:username-localhost-8889|44:YjdmMTExODQyNjNmNGM5MWIzZmM0OWIzYjE3NDgzZmM=|43a55e40b88869d8e054546feca0fbf7efae9c993b450311f5046f4c0ba45a66\"; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1526395222|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ZDJmZWNjZWUzZDJjNDVmMjkwMTZhNWZmNTI1MjhhMTE=|9cd671557f9b67b203088e3852aaf37de56ad7c8ad45f26798bc3e0d47a49c43\"",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Writing_MVUE_2d.ipynb",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|f34c78bf|7c7913196386a495e7fb6a7c3c7bbf7e|1525206477",
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
      "Content-Length": "0",
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Host": "localhost:8888"
    }
[E 10:49:44.698 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/contents/Writing_MVUE_2d.ipynb/checkpoints (::1) 12.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Writing_MVUE_2d.ipynb`

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some great debugging from deniz195 led to a great answer! This temporary solution works for me and many other github friends!

Quoting his original answer here:

> I debugged the issue a little bit and found the following solution:
>
> **Part 1 - Minimal working example**
>   The issue seems to originate from shutil.copyfile, which checks if source and destination file are the same (using os.path.samefile).
>
> It appears that the combination of windows and google drive file stream yields invalid results. Here is the minimum example (assuming G:\My Drive\foo.txt exists, using python 3.6.2):
>
> ```
> >>> f1 = 'G:\\My Drive\\foo.txt'
> >>> f2 = 'G:\\My Drive\\foo2.txt'
> >>> import shutil
> >>> shutil.copyfile(f1, f2)
> >>> shutil.copyfile(f1, f2)
> ```
>
> --> The last line throws the SameFileError although it clearly shouldnt!
>
> Whereas:
>
> ```
> >>> f1 = 'G:\\My Drive\\foo.txt'
> >>> f3 = 'C:\\Scratch\\foo2.txt'
> >>> import shutil
> >>> shutil.copyfile(f1, f3)
> >>> shutil.copyfile(f1, f3)
> ```
>
> --> Throws no error (correct)!
>
> **Part 2 - Why?**
>   How does this happen?
>
> It turns out that shutil.copyfile uses os.path.samefile to determine if a file is being copied on itself:
>   (from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/genericpath.py)
>
> ```
> # Are two filenames really pointing to the same file?
> def samefile(f1, f2):
>     """Test whether two pathnames reference the same actual file"""
>     s1 = os.stat(f1)
>     s2 = os.stat(f2)
>     return samestat(s1, s2)
>
> # Are two stat buffers (obtained from stat, fstat or lstat)
> # describing the same file?
> def samestat(s1, s2):
>     """Test whether two stat buffers reference the same file"""
>     return (s1.st_ino == s2.st_ino and
>             s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev)
> ```
>
> Now unfortunately st_ino depends on windows on the file system ([Meaning of ST_INO (os.stat() output) in Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158182/meaning-of-st-ino-os-stat-output-in-windows-os)) and specifically is st_ino==0 for all files on Google Drive File Stream.
>
> **Part 3 - Where to go and who to blame?**
>   It seems that this error is an unlucky combination of a lazy filesystem (why not report some kind of uid as the inode?) and a naive os python library (Checking for file identity this way seems not to generalize well... why not check if st_ino==0?)
>
> **Part 4 - The dirty fix**
>
> 1. Find genericpath.py of your python library:
>
> ```
> >>> import os
> >>> os.path.genericpath.__file__
> 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Anaconda3_64\\lib\\genericpath.py'
> ```
>
> 1. In this file, replace the samestat function with the following patch:
>
> ```
> # Are two stat buffers (obtained from stat, fstat or lstat)
> # describing the same file?
> def samestat(s1, s2):
>     """Test whether two stat buffers reference the same file"""
>     return (s1.st_ino != 0 and
>           s2.st_ino != 0 and
>           s1.st_ino == s2.st_ino and
>             s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev)
> ```
>
> 1. Save the file. Restart python (and/or jupyter).
> 2. Be happy and wait until either google or the python fixes this issue properly...

Comment: Regarding step #1 If you don't have Anaconda (e.g. installed Jupyter via pip) then probably you will find the file in this location: C:\Program Files\Python\Lib\genericpath.py

Comment: Worked for me! It wasn't too much of a big deal, since saving did work, just a nuisance